# How to add comma in selenium python after every two line?

Tags: python, selenium

Right now I am getting comma after every line but I need to insert comma after every two line. here is the  text that I am working on.
**specification of product:**

> ```
> LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER
> 31358DC2
> EAN NUMMER
> 4005176465017
> ```

here is My code:

```
specification.text.replace("\n",",").strip()
```

My this code giving me comma after end of every line but I need comma after every two line. here is my result:

```
LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER,31358DC2,EAN NUMMER,4005176465017
```

**my expected result will be something like this:**

```
LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER 31358DC2,EAN NUMMER 4005176465017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this line to join each two lines with comma:

```
from itertools import izip_longest as izip # For Python 2
from itertools import zip_longest as izip # For Python 3

splitted = specification.text.split('\n')
text = ', '.join([' '.join([first, second]) if second else first for first, second in izip(splitted[::2], splitted[1::2])])
print(text)
```

Output:

```
'LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER 31358DC2, EAN NUMMER 4005176465017'
```

P.S. If you know that number of lines will always be even then you can simplify solution and solve the issue with just `zip`:

```
text = ', '.join([' '.join([first, second]) for first, second in zip(splitted[::2], splitted[1::2])])
```

Comment: Thnkas JaSON. It worked but izip is not working  my current python version. After replaced  izip with zip it's working.

Comment: @FarhanAhmed I used `izip` instead of `zip` because `zip` works with only even number of elements (2, 4, 6...), but it won't work with odd number (3, 5, 7...). If it OK for you and you know that number of lines is always even then ok. Otherwise I'd recommend you to use zip function from itertools (note that you should import only one function: `izip_longest` in Python 2 or `zip_longest` in Python 3. Not both)

Comment: This can be solved without another library though

Answer (score 2):

You could write a generator that iterates lines in pairs. Join them with spaces then join *that* with commas.

```
text = """LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER
31358DC2
EAN NUMMER
4005176465017"""

def grab_2(seq):
    iseq = iter(seq)
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(iseq), next(iseq)
        except StopIteration:
            break

out = ",".join(" ".join(vals) for vals in grab_2(text.split("\n")))
print(out)
```

You can use the python shell to explore this solution and add functionality as needed.

```
>>> text = """LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER
... 31358DC2
... EAN NUMMER
... 4005176465017"""
>>> 
>>> def grab_2(seq):
...     iseq = iter(seq)
...     while True:
...         try:
...             yield next(iseq), next(iseq)
...         except StopIteration:
...             break
... 
>>>
```

Splitting the line gives you a list of lines, which you could process further if you'd like.

```
>>> lines = text.split("\n")
>>> lines
['LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER', '31358DC2', 'EAN NUMMER', '4005176465017']
```

Grabbing 2 lines at a time gives you tuples

```
>>> grabbed = list(grab_2(lines))
>>> for g in grabbed:
...     print(g)
... 
('LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER', '31358DC2')
('EAN NUMMER', '4005176465017')
```

These blocks can be processed in many ways. In addition to joining with spaces you could use a format specifier

```
>>> for g in grabbed:
...     print("{0};{1}\n".format(*g), end="")
... 
LEVERANDØRENS VARENUMMER;31358DC2
EAN NUMMER;4005176465017
```

Comment: your code didn't work for me. getting error "AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'split"

Comment: I converted your example to something that runs, and that's the gold standard for stackoverflow. Exactly how it fits in your code is something I can only guess at. Instead of `text.split` in my example, I suppose you'd use `specification.text.split` - that worked in the example fragment you posted so should work here.

Comment: Hi @ tdelaney thanks for the clarification. I was using specification.split after use specification.text.split as you said now it's working. Thanks

Comment: hi @ tdelaney can you please give me any documentation or any link for better understanding this topics. Assume I also want semicolon after every line and keep comma after every two line. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I would only recommend using this method if you are trying to avoid using external libraries. If you have access to libraries like itertools (mentioned in Jason's answer), you should use them.

---

This isn't entirely trivial. This function I've put together should do what you ask (with the added ability to do every-nth character, instead of just every two).

```py
def replaceEveryNth(string: str, replace: str, replace_with: str, n: int):
    out = ""
    str_frags = string.split(replace) #split the input string into substrings
    count = 1
    for frag in str_frags[:len(str_frags)-1]:
        out += frag #add substring to output string
        if count % n == 0: #Replace nth character
            out += replace_with
        else: #Use original character
            out += replace
        count += 1
    out += str_frags[len(str_frags)-1] #add last string fragment
    return out
```

In your particular situation you would use this like so:

```py
replaceEveryNth(text, "\n", ",", 2).replace("\n", " ")
```

Comment: Hi @John Paul R. I didn't get any error in my python shell but output is nothings see the image link1 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sbGDntZiG9SGVHtTkMCppApcRjnR4Zjt/view?usp=sharing  image link2 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fA1F2JkGkkJWYIeYINRB1czFscdwnfnu/view?usp=sharing